# Bokeh GMaps zoom tools not working

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I'm just starting to use the GMap functionality with Bokeh 0.12.16

I am trying to add some tools to a GMap plot, I know that `BoxZoomTool` [is not compatible](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5469), but I can't seem to get the others to work?

The `HoverTool`, `PanTool` and `SaveTool` work fine. Is it the case that no zoom tools work with GMap plots?

My code snippet below:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
os.chdir(r'PATH')
file = 'FILE_NAME.csv' 
df = pd.read_csv(file, skipinitialspace=True) 

group = df[["ColA", "ColB", "ColC", "ColD"]]
my_source = ColumnDataSource(group)
#my_source.column_names

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, gmap
from bokeh.models import GMapOptions, ColumnDataSource

import numpy as np 
lat_lims = df.Latitude
#lat_lims
lon_lims = df.Longitude
#lon_lims

map_options = GMapOptions(lat=np.mean(lat_lims), lng=np.mean(lon_lims), zoom=6)

p = gmap(MY_API_KEY, map_options)
p.circle("Longitude",
         "Latitude",
         source=my_source, 
         size=5)


from bokeh.models import HoverTool, PanTool, ZoomInTool, ZoomOutTool, SaveTool
p.tools=[PanTool(), ZoomInTool(), ZoomOutTool(), SaveTool()]

from bokeh.models import HoverTool
p.add_tools( HoverTool(tooltips= [("TextA: ", "@ColA"),
                                    ("TextB: ", "@ColB")]))

show(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Bokeh `0.12.16` the only zoom tool that functions with Bokeh `GMapPlot` is the `WheelZoomTool`. This is because the other set plot ranges directly and this is not compatible with Google Maps API (Google Maps strictly control ranges and they are not settable by users directly). However, I think it might be possible to make `ZoomIn` and `ZoomOut` function. Please open a [GitHub feature request issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) if you'd like to propose this and discuss futher.

Comment: Thank you, will do!